# Creating object which can be passed to view

Tags: laravel-5

I want to make a loan repayment payment plan. I need to put 4 values in a row for each month (loan balance before month, monthly interest repaid, balance repaid and loan at the end of month). I can calculate all these data in controller but I am unable to pass them to view.

Calculation of all elements is ok but I am unable to pass the object to view.

public function show()
    {

```
    $fLoanAmount = 10000;
    $fAPR = 8.3;
    $iTerm = 12;
    $monthlyInterest = $fAPR/1200;

    $payment = round($this->calculateMonthlyPayments($fLoanAmount, $fAPR, $iTerm),2);

    for ($n = 0; $n < $iTerm; $n++) {

        $loanBalance = $fLoanAmount; 

          $monthlyInterest = $loanBalance * $fAPR/1200;

          $monthlyBalanceRepayment = $payment - $monthlyInterest;

          $fLoanAmount = $loanBalance - $monthlyBalanceRepayment;

          $paymentPlan = collect([

              'loanBalance' => $loanBalance,
              'monthlyInterest' => $monthlyInterest,
              'monthlyBalanceRepayment' => $monthlyBalanceRepayment,
              'loanAmmount' => $fLoanAmount,

          ]);

    }


     return view('plan', compact('paymentPlan'));


}
```

Comment: Would you mind posting the code of your `view`. Thanks

Comment: Basically I expected I could do 'at'foreach ($paymentPlan as $payment) {{$payment->loanBalance}} 'at'endforeach

Comment: As @DevinNorgarb says, you may post more code to elaborate. For now, please check your variable `$paymentPlan` in the for loop. Next iteration overwrites previous value of `$paymentPlan`. Declare it before for loop like `$paymentPlan = collect([]);` and use collection's methods to push arrays in that collection.